# ViewModel in Application?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it acceptable to initialize `ViewModel()` in `Application` instead of `Activity`?

It seems to work fine for me with Jetpack Compose,  but every tutorial I saw says to initialize it in `Activity` for unknown reasons (they mention "possible memory leaks", but give no proof).

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var isElementVisible by mutableStateOf(true)
}

// 1. Is this acceptable?
class MyApp : Application() {
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    onCreate(){
        super.onCreate()

        mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    }
}

// 2. Or is only this acceptable?
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of android's `ViewModel` is that it can be tied to the lifecycle of android components - activity, fragment or navigation destination. In your second example, `MainViewModel` will be destroyed when the `MainActivity` is destroyed. In the first example though, the ViewModel will be alive the whole time your app is running. You don't need a ViewModel for that, because it's basically a Singleton.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. But just to confirm two things: 1. `ViewModel` is not needed for `Application`, but if it was there would that create a memory leak? 2. So, a Singleton with `MutableState` or `MutableStateFlow` could be initialized in `Application` instead of `ViewModel` and it would work just fine with Compose? I'm not too convinced to have state holder in `Activity`, because it would be gone on every configuration change, so it makes more sense to me to have it in `Application`.

Comment: Yeah, there won't be any memory leak. Your `MainViewModel` doesn't have to extent `ViewModel` if you use it in your application, it's useless. Yes, you can create a singleton with `MutableState` and `MutableStateFlow` in Application, it'd work fine with compose. The whole point of ViewModel is to keep the data on configuration change, so if you use the viewmodel in activity as in your 2nd example, it won't go away on every configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

As per best practices mentioned on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#best-practices). View Models should be as close as possible to the Activity, fragment, or screen level composable function. It decides the scope of ViewModel, when the activity is destroyed *[except configuration changes]*, the associated ViewModel will be destroyed.

If you declare the ViewModel at application level, it will be destroyed when the app is destroyed. Scopes are also important to keep in mind for coroutines. Consider an example where you launch an coroutine with `viewModelScope`, but you closed that activity and moved to some other activity, in that case the coroutine should be stopped, since it is no longer needed. But if you define the ViewModel at application level the coroutine won't be stopped, since the ViewModel itself isn't destroyed.

Moreover, every activity/fragment should have its own ViewModel as a best practice.